# Wordpress elementor: how to get rid of the vertical line?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, google-web-designer

I created a new page on elementor, and this vertical line shows up and I don't know how to get rid of it. Does anyone know how to do so?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwkmN.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you created this using elementor then you can just remove that and if it's theme part then you can remove it from customization

and the best way to remove it is by using CSS.

if you can tell me the URL then I can give you the CSS code to remove this bar.